# OneDrive Search api does not support Expand query on ListItems

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I need to search for files with `.docx` extension in my `OneDrive`. So this bit is simple and it works using OneDrive search api. The piece that does not work, is that in the response, with each `DriveItem`, I also need the custom properties we created under `ListItem.Fields` associated with this `DriveItem`. These custom properties contain information I need to create some sort of a report.

Expanding `ListItem` seems to work on `root/children` resource without any search, but it does not solve my problem, I need the files with the .docx extension in their filenames, these files can be under root or any sub folder under the root.

So this request returns the CustomProperty with the response

```
/_api/v2.0/drives/[drive id]/root/children?select=*%2cwebDavUrl
%2csharepointIds&expand=listItem(select%3dfields%3bexpand%3dfields(select%3dCustomProperty))
```

But when I try to expand `ListItem` on the `DriveItems` returned from search query as below:

```
/_api/v2.0/drives/[drive id]/root/search(q='docx')?select=*%2cwebDavUrl%2csharepointIds&expand=listItem(select%3dfields%3bexpand%3dfields(select%3dCustomProperty))
```

I get an error:

```
Error: {"error":{"code":"notSupported","message":"The request is not supported by the system."}}
```

Is expanding `ListItem.Fields` on a `DriveItem` not supported in `OneDrive` Search api ?

If it is not, then is there another way for me to achieve what I want to do here? I am not trying to search on the `CustomProperty`, just want to retrieve that value as part of the response with its associated `DriveItem`.

Expectedly, I get same/similar error if I run this through `Microsoft Graph` Search api instead of `OneDrive` api.

One workaround I could do, 
is to first search for `.docx` files without the expand keyword and it will recursively search and return all `.docx` files in my `OneDrive`. Then I could make individual calls to request these items again one by one from `OneDrive` using their `DriveItem.Id` and the expanded `ListItem.Fields` property. That would be a terrible workaround though. Because instead of achieving what I need in a single request, I would have to make 1000s or 10000s of individual I/O requests (one per .docx file) to get the expanded `ListItem` properties..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/829) with the `/search` endpoint. Unfortunately, there isn't a good workaround available at the moment either. In order to retrieve the `ListItem` resources, you will need to retrieve each `DriveItem` from your search result directly:

```
/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?$expand=listItem
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. This workaround will be not be workable for us as we implement an enterprise admin level report that will have tenant wide view. It has to now make potentially 100.000s of requests for big enterprises everytime the report loads. Do you have any insights as to when can we expect this feature to be implemented in Search functionality ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. It's on their radar but I would still suggest posting it in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). It never hurts to amplify the need so the product group can prioritize this functionality. It will certainly get my vote. ;)